# Multiple counters using same class names (querySelectorAll) but different IDs for input fields

Tags: javascript

As for this example, I want to have 2 or more reusable Increment counters.

Each container will have:

- an increment button with the same class name: `.increment`.
- an input field with the same class name `.number` but different ID (`#speed` and `#km`) to update its values, with different step and value attributes. It could something to do with `this.id` but I'm not seeing it.

#### Expectation:

- When clicking on the selected event listener (increment button) it would update the input value from that container.

I am using a forEach wrapper to get all the increment class names: `getIncrements.forEach((getIncrement)`, but I do not know how to select and change the input values based on which button is clicked.

```js
const getIncrements = document.querySelectorAll('.increment');
const getValue = document.querySelector('.number');

getIncrements.forEach((getIncrement) => {
  getIncrement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getValue.stepUp(1);
  })
});
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <button class="increment">+</button>
  <input id="speed" class="number" type="number" value="20" step="10" />
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <button class="increment">+</button>
  <input id="km" class="number" type="number" value="10" step="15" />
</div>
```

#### EDITED WITH DECREMENT AND LOOPING A CONTAINER

```js
const counterContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".flex");

const getIncrements = counterContainers.querySelectorAll(".increment");
const getDecrements = counterContainers.querySelectorAll(".decrement");



counterContainers.forEach(counterContainer => {
  getIncrements.addEventListener("click", () => {
    getIncrements.nextElementSibling.stepUp(1);
  });
  getDecrements.addEventListener("click", () => {
    getDecrements.nextElementSibling.stepDown(1);
  });
})
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <button class="increment">+</button>
  <input id="speed" class="number" type="number" value="20" step="10" />
  <button class="decrement">-</button>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <button class="increment">+</button>
  <input id="km" class="number" type="number" value="10" step="15" />
  <button class="decrement">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the Event object passed to [event handler functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), it contains a reference to the clicked button (`event.target`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) instead `querySelector`, because in your case you always use the first input

```js
const getIncrements = document.querySelectorAll(".increment");

getIncrements.forEach(getIncrement => {
    getIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
        getIncrement.nextElementSibling.stepUp(1);
    });
});
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <button class="increment">+</button>
    <input id="speed" class="number" type="number" value="20" step="10" />
</div>

<div class="flex">
    <button class="increment">+</button>
    <input id="km" class="number" type="number" value="10" step="15" />
</div>
```

UPD with decrement:

```
const counterContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".flex");

counterContainers.forEach(c => {
    const getIncrement = c.querySelector(".increment");
    const getDecrement = c.querySelector(".decrement");
    const input = c.querySelector("input");

    getIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
        input.stepUp(1);
    });

    getDecrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
        input.stepDown(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great! And If I added another button, `decrement`. It would be the same way, right? By adding a new event listener for getDecrement and loop them.

Comment: In this case, need to look at the location of the decrement button. Most likely you would have to look for a container `const cont = document.querySelectorAll(".flex");` and search for buttons individually with `cont.querySeceltor('.decrement')`

Comment: I have edited my OP with the decrement functionality. What am I missing? Im looping the `.flex` container and getting the elements with those containers.

Comment: I see, add to declare all fields inside the loop. Many thanks, its a very clear explanation!